# What is the simplest way to calculate the type token ratio?

Tags: c++, vector, return

I'm working on a program that reads a text file and outputs the word count, character count, line count and the type token ratio. Type token ratio returns a float number of the ratio of number of unique words to the total number of words. Can I use vectors to do this?

```
float TextProfile::TTR(){ //ratio
  return 0.0;
};
```

What is the simplest way to calculate the type token ratio?

Comment: the what is a what now?  why don't you try something...

Comment: You should stop now and get the source code for the `wc` program in linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::set`. Iterate over the words, adding them to the set, then return the set size divided by the word count.